# directory '/var/lib/mercurial-server/' is missing

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-server

After reinstall mercurial-server, directory '/var/lib/mercurial-server/' missing

```
apt-get purge mercurial-server
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mercurial-server
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mercurial mercurial-server
```

i try:

```
shabak@Ubuntu:/etc/mercurial-server$ cd /var/lib/mercurial-server
-bash: cd: /var/lib/mercurial-server: No such file or directory
```

I can't find the folder 'repos'.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install script creates and initializes that directory only if the "hg" user doesn't exist.  Otherwise it assumes you have an existing setup it should use.  Try adding these `deluser` and `delgroup` commands to what you're doing:

```
apt-get purge mercurial-server
deluser --remove-home --system hg
delgroup  --system hg
rm -rf /var/lib/mercurial-server
apt-get update
apt-get install mercurial mercurial-server
```

Alternately, before the "purge", do "dpkg-reconfigure mercurial-server" and set the option that destroys all data.

I'll detect and fix this in a future revision - thanks for reporting it!

Comment: Thank you, Paul! Its similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901715/mercurial-server-says-no-section-paths-must-be-run-as-the-hg-user

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that `mercurial-server` isn't part of the mercurial project?  It's a poorly maintained, third party application that does very little (nothing?) that mercurial can't already do without it.

If you're just trying to serve mercurial repositories consider using the hgweb program that came with Mercurial, or just use ssh access to the repositories in which case you need no software past the mercurial client at all.

Comment: What maintenance is it lacking specifically?  I haven't worked on it recently only because I'm not aware of any work needed - it's basically finished.